# C++ - trying to prototype a function within a class

Tags: c++, function, class

I just cannot understand why my prototype is not working. The code will run when i put the class above the main, but when i try to put it below and prototype the function it will not run. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int whileLoop();



int main (){

myLoop myLoopObj;

myLoopObj.whileLoop();


return 0;
}


class myLoop{

private:
    int loop = 0;
    int add = 0;
    int total = 0;


public:

   int whileLoop(){
    while (loop <= 10){
        cin >> add;
        total = add+ total;
        loop++;
    if (loop==10){
        cout << "you total is " << total;
    }
    }
    }


};
```

Comment: Class should be declared before it's first use. Read e.g. http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

Comment: Ok i tried to add class myLoop; as well as tried myLoop:whileLoop; and tried with adding int type but nothing is working, does this mean the only way is from a header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prototype is needless, here, as you're declaring the function inside the class, then calling the method from within the class.

Normally, when you prototype class methods, you do so in the class declaration, so you can define the method/methods separately. You are not doing either of these things, so your "function prototype" is not needed.

Not only is it not needed, but it's not in the right place. Function prototypes are declared before `main()`. Method prototypes are declared within class declarations.

It looks like you want to be able to call the class before your declaration. If you want to do that, you'll have to include the class with a preprocessor directive. Otherwise, you'll have to define your class before `main()`.

**Edit:**

I think you're confusing function prototypes with classes. Classes are not functions, so you cannot "prototype" a class like you can a function.

You basically have 3 options:

1. Declare the class before main()
2. Include the class from a separate file using #include
3. Include a .h header file with your class definition

Option 3 is sort of like prototyping, but it's not the same as what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh man this sounds too crazy ... so there is no simple solution as i am just completely doing this wrong?

Comment: @brigitte18 Sorry, let me simplify it; you can either declare your class before main, or "include" the class from a seperate file. You could create a new .cpp, define the class there, and then use #include 'myclass.cpp', for example.

Comment: Ohhh ok so create a new class in a .cpp and a .h header file and include it on main.cpp. So thats the only way to prototype a class before main and be able to call the function within it during main.cpp runtime. thank you so much for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @brigitte18: Yes, you could create a separate class definition as well, but that's an additional step. All you need to do is put your class in a separate file and include the cpp file.

Comment: @MartynShutt _"Normally, when you prototype class methods, you do so in the class definition"_, Wrong! That's called **class declaration**, class definition means the actual implementation.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ well spotted. I've corrected it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your **main** function is what runs your program.

Your **class** has to be defined before it is first used.

However, if you want your main before your class, the usual way is to create a **header** file and include it before your main().

Comment: Not true. It is sufficient for it to be declared.

Comment: @ChristianHackl no, you cannot instantiate a class that hasn't been defined.

Comment: @user2079303: Yes, if you use any member function, then you need the definition.

Comment: Ok i tried to add class myLoop; as well as tried myLoop:whileLoop; and tried with adding int type but nothing is working, does this mean the only way is from a header file?

Comment: @user2079303 _" no, you cannot instantiate a class that hasn't been defined."_ That's wrong. You can well instantiate a class that was declared. You need full definition, to make the linker happy.

Comment: isnt that the point of prototyping? it is at the bottom of main function, and i am defining it as a class... im sorry can you show me an example i am only 2 days new to c++

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm confused. How does the compiler know the size of the class if it wasn't defined yet? Doesn't it need to know that to instantiate?

Comment: @user2079303 The size can be fully deduced from the declaration. May be you're confusing _forward declaration_ with _class declaration_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, the size can only be deduced from the declaration if it is also the definition. Otherwise it's a forward declaration (or a redeclaration). I  suppose I was wrong to equate declaration with forward declaration since definitions are also declarations. On the other hand, equating declaration of class with it's definition is as erroneus.

Comment: @user2079303 _"... be deduced from the declaration if it is also the definition"_ No, you're still confusing the correct terminology. Go read the link from the very 1st comment on the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [that article](http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html) states that classes can be declared without defining them. As an example of such **declaration** it gives `class MyClass;`. The article does not mention that such **declarations** are also called forward declarations, though that is correct. The article also states: *Because the compiler needs to know the size of the variable an_object, and it can't do that from the **declaration** of MyClass;* which indicates that the author uses declaration to mean forward declaration which is what I did.

Comment: @user2079303 You're right, the article uses the wrong terminology either.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I and the article are consistent with the standard which typically uses declaration and forward declaration of a class interchangeably. And typically calls `class T{};` a definition. I do agree that calling definition of a class a declaration such as you do is not technically incorrect because all definitions are also declarations. It's  just a bit confusing if you try to imply that you're not talking about a forward declaration but a definition. It seems that I, the article and the standard are all in the wrong. Sorry to have bothered you.

Answer (score 0):

1) A class must be defined before any of it's member functions are called (or it's declared as a member of another class). `main` instantiates a `myLoop` (which implies a call to the constructor which is a member function) and calls a member function `myLoop::whileLoop`. Therefore `myLoop` must be defined before `main` .

2) You didn't declare `myLoop::whileLoop` member function. You declared a `whileLoop` non-member function. Member functions can only be declared in the definition of the class.

> Ok i tried to add class myLoop; as well as tried myLoop:whileLoop; and tried with adding int type but nothing is working, does this mean the only way is from a header file?

`class myLoop;` is only a declaration without the definition (a forward declaration). So, it isn't enough. `myLoop:whileLoop;` that declaration won't work. As I said, you need to declare member functions inside the definition of the class.

If you only use the class in that compilation unit (source file), then you can certainly define it there if you don't want to use a header. But it must be defined before declaring variables of the type or calling it's members. Before main in your case. Headers are very handy if you need the class in several compilation units and for organizing your code.

Comment: Ok i tried to add class myLoop; as well as tried myLoop:whileLoop; and tried with adding int type but nothing is working, does this mean the only way is from a header file?

Comment: @user2079303 _"`class myLoop;` is only a declaration, not a definition"_ It's a **forward declaration** to be precise. Class declaration means something different.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ forward declarations are declarations. I've made my answer more explicit.